# How can I format my array elements?

Tags: java, arrays

This is what I have so far:

```
public class Numbers
{
    // Fields
    public int[] numberLine;
    public int randomNumber;
    public Random randomGen;


    // Constructor : Initialise number array
    public Numbers()
    {
        numberLine = new int[6];
        randomNumber = 0;
        randomGen = new Random();
    }

    // Method : Generate 6 random numbers in a range 1 to 49
    public void populateArray()
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < numberLine.length; index++)
        {
            randomNumber = 1 + randomGen.nextInt(49);
            numberLine[index] = randomNumber;
        }
        Arrays.sort(numberLine);
    }

    ...
}
```

This code will create an array of six integers and populated by random numbers (1 - 49) using the for loop then sorts the elements into ascending order.

What I would like to do after that is have a method print the array elements in the following format:

```
** nn nn nn nn nn nn **
```

Normally this could be done using:

```
System.out.println(""** " + numberLine[0] + " " + numberLine[1]...
```

And so on...

However, since there is the possibility of some of the numbers having only one digit, how would one go about ensuring the proper format by leaving a black space?

So that it would look like this (example numbers):

```
**  7  9 27 37 39 48 **
```

Notice the extra space in front of the single digit elements. I've thought of something like:

```
for(int index = 0; index < numberLine.length; index++)
{
    if(numberLine[index] <= 9)
    {
        singleDigit++;

    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

that could then be used in something like:

```
for(int index = 0; index < numberLine.length; index++)
{
    if(index < singleDigit)
    {
        //make the single digit have a space before it
    }
}
```

But I can't think of a way to make that work since an array of integers can only contain integer values so I'm probably not on the right lines with that method. It could, perhaps, be done with an array of strings but then sorting them into ascending order could get complicated.

Anyone know how I could get it to print in the required format?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Something I just thought might work is to use this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < numberLine.length; index++)
{
    if(numberLine[index] <= 9)
    {
        singleDigit++;

    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

and then use something like:

```
if(singleDigit = 0)
{
    System.out.println("** " + numberLine[0] + " " + numberLine[1]
        + " " + numberLine [3] //etc
}
else
{
    if(singleDigit = 1)
    {
        System.out.println("**  " + numberLine[0] + " " +
            numberLine[1] + " " + numberLine [3]
             // etc (notice the extra space between the first ""
    }
}
```

And continue that all the way up to `singleDigit = 6`. That should work, I think, but there must be an easier/tidier way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    System.out.print("** ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numberLine.length; i++) {
        if (numberLine[i] < 10) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print(numberLine[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("**");
```

Basically, you print part of the string as you go along, checking if you need to add numbers as you go.

Comment: This looks like it will do what I want, I'll have to test it quickly. shouldn't I use: System.out.print("**\n"); at the end to ensure that the next time something prints it will be on the next line?

Comment: Tested. This seems to be it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do so using `System.out.printf`, using the format `%d` for integer, and adding a width specifier of 2 before the `d`, eg:

```
System.out.printf("%2d, %2d, %2d, %2d, %2d\n", 15, 5, 35, 3, 4);
```

Output:

```
15,  5, 35,  3,  4
```

`System.out.printf` is equivalent to `System.out.format` and you can find more information about format strings [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

**EDIT:** If you wanted your output to instead be `15, 05, 35, 03, 04`, then simply change the above code to:

```
System.out.printf("%02d, %02d, %02d, %02d, %02d\n", 15, 5, 35, 3, 4);
```

Take note of the `02` now in front of the `d` and after the `%`. This means that any missing digits will be replaced by `0` as opposed to a space.

Comment: I like the simplicity here.  It should be noted that since `printf` takes varargs an array will work instead of the comma separated list.  However, the downside is that the format string must have at least the same number of specifiers as the number of arguments, so you end up writing code to create the format specifier string.

Answer (score 0):

These lines will do the trick:

```
System.out.print("** ");
for (int e : numberLine)
    System.out.printf("%2d ", e);
System.out.println("**");
```

I'm using Java's string formatter, take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for all the details, but basically the `"%2d "` part is saying: pad a number with spaces to the left, in such a way that it always has a length of exactly two characters.

Answer (score 0):

In beginner coding terms we can use substring method as follows:

```
int n = 22; //integer bet 1-49
String str = " "+ n;
System.out.println(str.substring(str.length()-2,str.length()));
```

thus, always printing a a string of length of 2.

Answer (score -1):

You can use number formatter for this. Such as

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");
String s = formatter.format(7);  // that print 07
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This will add a zero in front of the number (like this `07`) instead of a space as requested by the OP (like this ` 7`)

Comment: You're in the ballpark, Pritom, but as you noted that will output `07`.  If you change your format to `#0` the leading digit will be blank which is better, but the person asking the question wanted a leading space.